# Button push down effect on <a> button

Tags: css, button

So I have button defined by the a-tag which says:

```css
.button {
  background: #aaaaaa;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #999999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #a1a1a1
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #999999;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Click me</a>
```

So pretty straight forward. A button, a hover effect, and an active effect. However, what I would actually like is the effect of pushing the button. Now the box-shadow just disappears, but the button itself doesn't go "down" so to speak...

It's pretty easy with just a  button, but I need this for a -button. Can it be done ? :)

Comment: It can be done. No problem. `<a>` has some default css properties like `text-decoration` and `'color` etc for each state like `active, `hover, visited` etc. First of all, you need to override the properties. Then give it the same styles that you have given to the `button`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `position: relative` to the button and add `top: -1px` on `:active` for `1px` top offset.

```css
.button {
  background: #aaaaaa;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #999999;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #a1a1a1
}

.button:active {
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Click me</a>
```

Comment: a border bottom and margin top on active would also suffice, looks more realistic too imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that manually like that :

```
.button {
padding: 15px 25px;


font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

.button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_buttons_animate3

Or you could also use the material design through the materialize package:

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_material.asp

And this is an example for buttons :

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>
```

http://materializecss.com/buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transform scale property. This will make an illusion that the button is clicked since it becomes smaller on active.

```
.button {
      transition: all 1s;
}
.button:active {
     transform:scale(0.8,0.8);
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_scale